# JWT get user id in Blade template Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, jwt

I installed JWT Auth, and for now everything works well. But I have problem to get current user id, or @guest to work. I'm getting some JSON page when I enter
[image]

```
{{auth()->guard('api')->user()->id}}
```

But on xdebug I'm getting user id

[image]

Do I miss something?

Comment: in view you can get logged user id with {{Auth::user()->id}}

Comment: I know that, but does not work with JWT